# How to use io.socket in Node - Express Framework

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to use io.socket onto a node js application.

In server side:

```
 io.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('event', function(data){console.log("I am here")});
    client.on('disconnect', function(){});
 });
```

In client side:

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('news', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});

server.listen('80');
app.listen(port);
```

But I think I have some problem with the port because the port is defined under folder bin/www.

when i try to upload the code into heroku, the heroku app is broken down. It was working fine in localhost.

Comment: What does `heroku log` say ?

Comment: I will try to reproduce the problem in Heroku log. I think it is because I use Express 4x. As I do some research, the Express 4x automatically generate the bin/www folder. I am still stuck with io.socket, and trying to make it run..